# How to fix "can't invoke button command" in python using tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm attempting tkinter in python fo the first time but the Button command creates an error

```py
from tkinter import *
RandomWindow = Tk()
Close = RandomWindow.destroy()
RandomButton = Button(RandomWindow, text = "Click to shuffle and select cards", command = Close)
RandomButton.pack()
```

It should create a window with a button but I just receive the error message

```sh
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed
```

Answer (score 1):

You already destroyed the window where you assign `RandomWindow.destroy()` to `Close`.

Here is what you probably meant:

```
def Close(): RandomWindow.destroy()
```

Use that instead of `Close = RandomWindow.destroy()`

Comment: Python functions and methods are objects (just plain ordinary variables), so your close function is useless.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
Close = RandomWindow.destroy()
```

you are actually *calling* the window's `destroy` method, so when you hit the next line:

```
RandomButton = Button(RandomWindow, ...)
```

you are passing an already destroyed window to your button, hence the error.

You want:

```
Close = RandomWindow.destroy # no parens, just reference the method
RandomButton = Button(
    RandomWindow, 
    text="Click to shuffle and select cards", 
    command=Close
)
```

or even more simply:

```
RandomButton = Button(
    RandomWindow, 
    text="Click to shuffle and select cards", 
    # no parens, just reference the method
    command=RandomWindow.destroy
 )
```